# Perl: Some websites block non-browser requests. But how?

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

I'm writing a simple Perl script that fetches some pages from different sites. It's very non-intrusive. I don't hog a servers bandwidth. It retrieves a single page without loading any extra javascript, or images, or style sheets.

I use LWP::UserAgent to retrieve the pages. This works fine on most sites but there are some sites that return a "403 - Bad Request" error. The same pages load perfectly fine in my browser. I have inspected the request header from my webbrowser and copied that exactly when trying to retrieve the same page in Perl and every single time I get a 403 error. Here's a code snippet:

```
use strict;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $URL = "https://www.betsson.com/en/casino/jackpots";

my $browserObj = LWP::UserAgent->new(
  ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 }
);

# $browserObj->cookie_jar( {} );
my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new();
$browserObj->cookie_jar( $cookie_jar );

$browserObj->agent( "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0");
$browserObj->timeout(600);
push @{ $browserObj->requests_redirectable }, 'POST';

my @header = ( 'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
               'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
               'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
               'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
               'DNT' => '1',
               'Host' => 'www.bettson.com',
               'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' => '1'
             );

my $response = $browserObj->get( $URL, @header );
if( $response->is_success ) {
  print "Success!\n";
} else {
  print "Unsuccessfull...\n";
}
```

How do these servers distinguish between a real browser and my script? At first I thought they had some JavaScript trickery going on, but then I realized in order for that to work, the page has to be loaded by a browser first. But I immediately get this 403 Error.

What can I do to debug this?

Comment: There are several ways to detect bots. It is impossible to say what your specific but **unknown** site is doing by only having your code and the information that this code does not work to bypass the bot detection.

Comment: "There are several ways to detect bots". Can you name one that works without the server looking at the headers being sent? And that doesn't rely on javascript in the page being served?

Comment: *"...without the server looking at the headers being sent..."* - why not look at the headers? Just because you think that you took the headers from the browser does not mean that LWP sends the header exactly as the browser. It will change the order (sort), add a TE header, has its own User-Agent, fiddle with the Connection header... - see https://pastebin.com/MnsaY2hv. And thus you get a request header which is not typical for a browser. Looking at the headers is one of the easiest things for bot detection, i.e. if these are already atypical then no need to use more advanced methods.

Comment: The headers are exactly the same (as confirmed by a traffic sniffer). Except for perhaps order but that also differs from browser to browser. As you can see in my code above, the User Agent is copied from my browser. There is no discernible difference between the headers sent by the browser and by my script (other than order but again, that differs from browser to browser).

Comment: Did you try to use cookies file from your browser in `$cookie_jar`? There is a pretty good chance that cookies are set with some javascript which your perl script is not capable of.

Comment: Well, the request succeeds on a browser without cookies being sent.If some Javascript is setting cookies then the page needs to be served first. And like I said, I don't get the page. I immediately get a 403 error. I can include the URL of the page I'm trying to read but I'm pretty sure it will constitute as spam.

Comment: @Zippy1970: *"...the User Agent is copied from my browser...."* - ok, I forgot to copy this line to my code. But there is still difference in order, there is the TE header and there is the difference in the `Connection` string as can be seen in the pastebin. *"other than order but again, that differs from browser to browser"* -  bot detection does not work by checking a specific header but by comparing a fingerprint with stored fingerprints of typical browsers. Browsers have different but fairly static fingerprints and the one from LWP is different.

Comment: @Zippy1970: and again, without knowing the specific web site and doing some tests it is impossible to know what technique this specific site employs  - which means your question cannot be answered without this detail. Speculating about what all might be possible reasons without any kind of reality check is just useless. *"I can include the URL of the page I'm trying to read but I'm pretty sure it will constitute as spam"* - why should it, it is pretty common for OP to add such detail. You don't need to add it as link, just include it into the code.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the code and  included the proper domains. Hope I don't get banned for this. I will remove the URLs again if/when they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While 403 is a typical answer for bot detection, in this case the bot detection is not the cause of the problem. Instead a typo in your code is:

```
my $URL = "https://www.betsson.com/en/casino/jackpots";
...
               'Host' => 'www.bettson.com',
```

In the URL the domain name is `www.betsson.com` and this should be reflected in the `Host` header. But your `Host` header is slightly different: `www.bettson.com`. Since the Host header has the wrong name the request is rejected with 403 forbidden.

And actually, it is not even needed to go through all this trouble since it looks like no bot detection is done at all. I.e. no need to set user-agent and fiddle with the headers but plain:

```
my $browserObj = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $browserObj->get($URL);
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.

Comment: @Quentin: I can understand you arguments but I have also arguments to keep the answer: it is not an obvious typo which results in a syntax error. It  is instead a problem which results in a 403 forbidden response. This is actually a typical response for bot detection. Thus, users looking for this kind of problem might find value in this answer since they see that there might be other reasons apart from bot detection which cause this kind of error. I've made this more clear in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the URLS incorrectly. My test program does contain the proper URLs. And yes, it does work now.For reasons unknown to me, sometimes it works for a few days, then it stops working for months at end.

Comment: Ok, sorry for all the confusion but... You were right. The snippet I posted above was just part of the script I'm using here and I made the same typo in another spot. And now having corrected both of them, it does seem to work. Still not sure why it sometimes worked *with* the typo, but well... There you go.